# rerender part of parent window from a popup window

Tags: jsp, jsf, popup

I have a xhtml page with a button that opens a popup window, I want to reRender part of the parent xhtml page from the popup window ( for example by clicking a button on popup, I want to reRender part of the parent window). I have read a few post , most of them give up by not using a popup window 
(I  don't like popups but in this case I have no choice)

Does anyone know a solution for this problem?

Comment: How are you opening the popup? The term "reRender" which you're consistently using there suggests that you're using RichFaces. Is this true? In any case, posting an SSCCE of how you're opening and managing the popup would help a lot to get started. At least, it should be not any different if the popup is represented by a `<div>`  overlay in the very same view/document. The story changes when you're using `window.open()`.

Comment: I use "window.open" to open the popup window, my parent window is xhtml page with richfaces but my popup is a jsp page. For the first step I tried to get an element from the parent with "window.opener.document.getElementById" , but it doesn't work

Comment: More details would still be highly appreciated. Which JSF version? Which JSF component libraries? An SSCCE? Your question is in its current form way too broad. I could post an answer showing how to do that with PrimeFaces, but then you may say "No I can't because I'm using JSF 1.x" or "No I can't because I'm using the deprecated JSP technology" or "No I can't because I'm restricted to RichFaces", etc

Comment: my final goal is changing an icon of a button in the parent window by clicking a button on the child window

Comment: I am using jsp2.1 and richfaces 4.2.0. Project was written with jsp and recently some pages converted to jsf, because of that my parent window is JSF and my pop up is in jsp.

Comment: I strongly recommend to replace JSP by Facelets so that you can simply use `<rich:popupPanel>` and continue using `<a4j:ajax render>` the usual way.